# Need to sort results in HTML

Tags: html, web-services, sorting

I need to sort my campaign results in descending order using timstamp values.how to sort it?

```
<div class="campaign_area" ng-controller="CampaignAreaController" ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns">
                    <div class="campaign_card">
                        <div class="campaign_name">{{campaign.CampaignName}}</div>
                        <div class="campaign_options">
                            Execution Date: {{campaign.StartTimeStamp | date:'medium'}} | Result: {{campaign.Status}} | 
                            <a href="#" ng-click="handleDetailsClick($event, campaign.CampaignId)">{{detailsMsg}}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You can use NG filter "orderBy" https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: thank you for your quick reply..As i am new to html please provide more explanations.please..code is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used Angular filtering yet. But i see what's happening in docs so I will try to answer you.

When you use `ng-repeat` you can sort the result with `orderBy` filter.
The syntax is : `ng-repeat="item in array | orderBy : parm1 : parm2"`

`parm1` is object property name in the array. For example:

```
var persons = [
{name: 'John', otherProp: 'some other prop'}, 
{name: 'Anna', otherProp: 'some other prop'}, 
{name: 'Ben', otherProp: 'some other prop'}
];
```

`parm2` is "reverse" option. If is set to `true` the sorting will be reversed. Else will not be.

So if we have:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:name:false">
{{person.name}}
</div>
```

In this expression: "`| orderBy:name:false`". The word `"name"` pointing at `person.name`.
So angular will sort the result with `person.name`.

In your case you can do something like this:

```
<div class="campaign_area" ng-controller="CampaignAreaController" 
ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns | orderBy:StartTimeStamp:true">
```

The true param will output descending (reversed) result.